# Update data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I have a small problem updating rows of one table with data from another one, please help.

Table `l` with columns

```
Make
Model
OEMNumberLatest
OemNumberPrevious
cStockCode
cDescription
```

The two columns `cStockCode`,`cDescription` are blank at the moment and are waiting to be populated, and the second table `c` with columns `StockCode` and `Description`

The question is how to move/copy contents of table `c` into rows of table `l`?

Where `c.StockCode = l.OEMNumberLatest` and or `c.StockCode = l.OemNumberPrevious`

Comment: join the tables and do the update ?

Comment: Please post the table DDL so we can see how the tables look like.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't *move* the contents of one table into the other.  It is really better to just get the values when you need them, using a join:

```
select l.*, c.cStockCode, c.cDescription
from table1 l join
     c
     on c.StockCode = l.OEMNumberLatest or c.StockCode = l.OemNumberPrevious;
```

This seems like a strange condition, with the `or` because you can get multiple matches.

In any case, you can convert this to an `update` easily:

```
update table1 l join
       c
       on c.StockCode = l.OEMNumberLatest or c.StockCode = l.OemNumberPrevious
    set l.cStockCode = c.cStockCode,
        l.cDescription = c.cDescription;
```

When both conditions match, then one will arbitrarily be used for the `update`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a example of a update syntax using another table

```
UPDATE tableL SET
tableL.cStockCode=tableC.StockCode,tableL.cDescription=tableC.Description
FROM tableL
JOIN tableC   ON 
(tableC.StockCode = tableL.OEMNumberLatest) 
OR 
(tableC.StockCode = tableL.OemNumberPrevious);
```

I assument that the contents in `tableC` is to be filled in `tableL` , and the `JOIN` is based on `StockCode` with `OEMNumberLatest` or `OemNumberPrevious`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (save your data before trying, I am not sure of your database structure) :

```
UPDATE l
SET l.cStockCode = c.StockCode, l.cDescription = c.Description 
FROM l
INNER JOIN c ON (c.StockCode = l.OEMNumberLatest OR c.StockCode = l.OemNumberPrevious)
```